# Ubuntu doesn't detect hdmi connection

Tags: intel-graphics, hdmi

Whenever I try to connect my laptop on my TV through HDMI connection, it doesn't work (VGA does).

Here is the output for `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768       60.1*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1440x900_60.00   59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080_60.00   60.0  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The resolution found on HDMI1 was get from my `.xprofile`:

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1440x900_60.00"
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

I'm using Intel core i5 with HD graphics 3000.

Does anyone know the workaround for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I have an Intel HD Graphics 3000 and it works just fine.

Comment: Try to force `HDMI1` to show ouptut. Run  `xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00` May help

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem a while ago too, and for me the problem was two-fold:

1. My on-board Intel graphics doesn't recognize my HDMI port; only the internal laptop screen and the VGA port.

   **Solution:**

   - Turn on the nVidia card in my BIOS.
     (Note: `Hybrid` doesn't work: It *needs* to be `Intel` or `NVidia`)
   - [Install the nVidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)
2. **if** the HDMI cable is a good one, it needs to be firmly plugged into the port.

   **Solution:**

   Push the cable **really hard** into the slot.